# Посчитать конкурс на каждую специальность SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть две таблицы - абитуриенты (список всех абитуриентов и список специальностей, куда они подали документы) и таблица специальности (названия специальностей и кол-во мест на каждую).
Нужно посчитать конкурс на каждую специальность (отношение числа поданных заявлений к числу мест). И упорядочить специальности в порядке убывания конкурса.
Единственное до чего я дошел - посчитал кол-во поданных заявлений на каждую специальность (думаю, что правильно).

`SELECT Специальность, COUNT(Специальность) AS qty FROM Абитуриенты GROUP BY Специальность`

Comment: С учётом того, что один абитуриент подаёт заявление на несколько специальностей, схема выглядит некорректной.

Comment: @Akina тем не менее конкурс считается так.

Comment: @teran Я о структуре хранения. То, что конкурс считается независимо от заявления на другую специальность, я знаю - поэтому и существует общий конкурс в ВУЗ и конкурсы по отдельным специальностям.

Comment: @Akina а что со структурой, многие-ко-многим. чего еще надо от нее?

Comment: @teran Так ведь нет у него много-ко-много, у него много-к-одному. Две таблицы. И ещё непонятно, как в первой хранится список - по тексту создаётся впечатление, что таблица абитуриентов денормализована..

Comment: @Akina я тоже сначала подумал, что нет. Потом подумал что у него два таблицы абитуриентов (сами + связь) + справочник специальностей. Теперь правда тоже думаю, что денормализованная.

Answer (score 0):

Видимо что-то вроде такого

```
SELECT s.id, s.title
     , count(app_specs.app_id)
     , count(app_specs.app_id)/s.pcount AS x
FROM specs
LEFT JOIN app_specs ON (app_specs.spec_id = s.id)
GROUP BY s.id, s.title
ORDER BY x DESC
```

сама таблица абитуриентов в целом тут не нужна. достаточно таблицы специальностей и таблицы связи многие ко многим, где указаны, кто и куда подал заявления.